# Lemma of Farkas, as a an application of Separation Theorems of Hahn Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

I got stuck in a math problem i recently got in functional analysis:

It's some kind of Lemma of Farkas but i can't find it somewhere in the Internet:

Let X be a real locally convex space and $\xi, \xi_{1},...,\xi_{n} \in X^{'}$
, such that if x ∈ X with $\xi_{i}(x) \ge 0$ for all $i = 1, . . . , n$, then $\xi(x) \ge 0$. Show the existence of $a_i \ge 0$ such that $\xi = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i \xi_i$.

As a hint i got that i have to use a separation theorem (of Hahn Banach) on $\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \xi_i | a_i \ge 0 \, \text{for } i = 1,...,n  \}$.

I would appreciate any kind of help! Thank you!

Comment: Consider the cones $C_1 = \operatorname{cone} \{ \xi_k \}$, $C_2 =  \operatorname{cone} \{ \xi \}$. The above says that $C_1^* \subset C_2^*$. Can you conclude that $C_2 \subset C_1$?

Comment: @copper.hat what do you mean exactly by cone{$\xi_k$}  in this kind of problem? Thank you!

Comment: The convex cone generated by $\xi_k$.

Comment: Another way to prove this would be to show that, from the assumptions, if $\xi_{i}(x)  = 0$ then $\xi(x) = 0$. And the rest is a well known fact listed, for example, in Rudin's "Functional Analysis"

Comment: @Salcio Well, I don't think it is that easy. I guess you mean the ''well known fact'' that $\xi$ is a linear combination of the $\xi_i$. But it is another matter to find a linear combination with positive coefficients.

Comment: @Jochen - once you have linear combination, the rest should follow from the fact that for each functional $\xi_j$ there is $x_j$ for which other functional are $0$.

Comment: It is not as simple as what Rudin does, he is showing the (simpler) result for kernels.